# How to create a signed-url using Node-red for Google cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, node-red

I am trying to create a flow where it can generate a pre-signed URL to view protected media on my google cloud storage bucket for a limited time. I tried using Google's node-red storage node which was able to write/read the objects but not a URL to view them. Is there any node or flow or an idea to start with retrieve/create a signed-URL using node-red?

Thanks

Prudhvi